# Solve the differential equation: $ (y\cos(x)+2xe^y)+(\sin(x)+x^2e^y-1)y'. $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solve the differential equation:
$$
(y\cos(x)+2xe^y)+(\sin(x)+x^2e^y-1)y'=0.
$$

I can rewrite the equation as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(y\sin(x)+x^2e^y-y)=0
$$
to get
$$
y\sin(x)+x^2e^y-y=C
$$
but how do I go from there?  I have that annoying $e^y$ term.

Comment: I think this is considered to be the solution. You don't need an explicit $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: It's an implicit solution, as it expresses $y$ implicitly. We cannot seem to solve for $y$ though, based on that $e^y$ term you have (and mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M= (y\cos(x)+2xe^y)$ and $ N=  (\sin(x)+x^2e^y-1) $ we have that $$M_y=N_x=\cos(x)+2xe^y$$ this shows that differential equation is complete and we have $$\int (y\cos(x)+2xe^y)\,dx-\int\,dy=C$$ so that we have $$y\sin(x)+x^2e^y-y=C$$